# flutter_google_places not showing autocomplete search results

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am following along with the tutorial from the following link on using Google Maps API to create a search function to look for places on a map:

[Medium.com flutter tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-places-location-search-with-map-view-using-flutter-1-0-alfian-losari-66cacb3bcc24)

Below is the code that I believe constitutes the core of the issue:

```
 /**
* Retrieves the user's location
* NOTE: This pretty much does the same thing as _animateToUser,
* but I separated the two
*/
Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
 var currentLocation = <String, double>{};
 final uLocation = LocationManager.Location();
try {
  currentLocation = await uLocation.getLocation();
  final lat = currentLocation["latitude"];
  final lng = currentLocation["longitude"];
  final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
  return center;
} on Exception {
  currentLocation = null;
  return null;
}
}

/**
 * Searches for locations using Google Maps API
*/
Future<void> _search() async {
try {
  final center = await getUserLocation();
  Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      strictbounds: center == null ? false : true,
      apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
      onError: onError,
      mode: Mode.overlay,
      language: "en",
      location: center == null
          ? null
          : Location(center.latitude, center.longitude),
      radius: center == null ? null : 10000);

  showDetailPlace(p.placeId);
} catch (e) {
  return;
}
}

/**
* Shows details of a place
*/
Future<Null> showDetailPlace(String placeId) async {
if (placeId != null) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
    PlaceDetailWidget(placeId)),
  );
 }
 } /**
 * Retrieves the user's location
 * NOTE: This pretty much does the same thing as _animateToUser,
 * but I separated the two
 */
Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
var currentLocation = <String, double>{};
final uLocation = LocationManager.Location();
try {
  currentLocation = await uLocation.getLocation();
  final lat = currentLocation["latitude"];
  final lng = currentLocation["longitude"];
  final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
  return center;
} on Exception {
  currentLocation = null;
  return null;
}
}`
```

The problem is that, no matter what I type into the search bar, it will not autocomplete/suggest anything.

Example: [image]

In this example I want to bring up a list of places that have the word grand in them like 'Grand Central Station', for instance.

Comment: Please check the log, I think it is showing error related to Google API.

Comment: Best way to implement custom auto complete places in flutter https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. The `_search()` function has a radius `radius: center == null ? null : 10000);` that it uses to calculate areas around you within the radius you give it. My emulator has my location as being in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean (separate issue, but very minor). Since there were no places that start with 'grand' near my location in the middle of the ocean, nothing was coming up. I increased the radius from `10000` to `10000000` and it started to find locations.

Comment: Also the emulator thinking I was in the Atlantic Ocean was my own mistake. With the emulator open I went to **Debug -> Location -> Custom Location...** and realized I had put my latitude and longitude incorrectly into the corresponding fields. Once I changed it and did a hot reload I was where I wanted to be.

Comment: still always loading to me after added radius sir

Answer (score 8):

Look in the console for errors. In my case, my billing was linked and relevent APIs was enabled, still it never show predictions. Then I added the following **strictBounds** & **types** as non-null values.

```
Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                  context: context,
                  apiKey: Local.googleMapsAPIKey,
                  radius: 10000000,
                  types: [],
                  strictbounds: false,
                  mode: Mode.overlay,
                  language: "fr",
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  components: [Component(Component.country, "fr")],
                );
```

Comment: types: [],
strictbounds: false,
The above two lines solved my issues. Previously it was throwing: null check operator used on a null value

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: perfect workaround for me

Answer (score 2):

Check if your billing its activate on Google APIS